# Super slow cannot check Yahoo mails

Tags: windows-server-2003

Am a dba just got this situation no system adm on site. System works fine at old location. Server is Windows Server 2003. has static ip with comcast and good speed of say 12mps. Now new location has anew static T1 connection of 2mps up and down.

Runs synchronizing of offline files with four computers including the server. All flat files. Has a switch that connects all nodes, router that has IP address to the T1 connection. T1 connection is shared with other users, no dhcp on router. It is set to do static.

Now all computers run dhcp except the server has two cards but we only use static ip connection on the server. Connecting to the internet is not consistent and slows. Say internet from the server is 70% success, but from the computers say 45% success. Now once you connect to yahoo.com, you cannot check mails. If you are able to check mails maybe 1% success all day. If you try others like Google mails then your chances increases to say 40%.

Now my LAN has a different set of subnet mask (all internal nodes are 255.255.255.0) compare to that of LAN subnet (255.255.255.242) on the router. Will that be a factor? 
Cannot get internet to be consistent. When i take the computer home, out of the network, it works perfect.

I recommended increasing the speed to say 10mps for the internet service. The yahoo.com mail is where the calendar and all stuff is for the company. Help me guys recommendations, solutions, and all.

Comment: My recommendation is that you contact your system administrator. There are lots of things that could cause your T1 to appear slow (from my experience Chris S is probably right about packet loss - either from a crap line or from saturation), and none of it is the responsibility of a DBA to fix...

Comment: At the moment i am the system admin. So u see what they got

Comment: @user, sorry this may seem offensive: Find someone who knows what they're doing. Call a consultant or whatever it takes. You are in way over your head and obviously do not have the requisite knowledge to find an adequate solution.

Answer (score 3):

While a T1 is "slow" compared to many other connections (it's 1.544Mbps too, not 2), it should bring up Yahoo Mail without a hitch. There are serious network problems somewhere. Find the admin and get him/her to fix it. Sounds like you've got massive packet loss (just an offhand guess).

Comment: Or some botnet mess inside the network.

Comment: @mfinni, that's possible too, I'm just thinking it's something simple like the CSU/DSU has it's clock source set to local and the line's slipping constantly... Could be a bad NIC that's chattering too... Or a million other things that the admin will be able to figure out pretty quickly.

Comment: Right right. We could spitball ideas all day :-)

Comment: all nodes are connected to a switch. when the wireless connects to the internet, they use the router. And the pc use the switch to the router. But the inconsistency is coming from the all. They dont go internet consistently and when they do mails is a problem.

Comment: "**Find the admin and get him/her to fix it.**"

Comment: if its a csu/dsu then the isp should be involved, matter of fact have you even tried calling the ISP? Sounds like your trying to be a long wolf but in this case you'll need some help.

Comment: csu/dsu does not apply. spoke with isp repre. Tks

Comment: also what do you mean by "T1 connection is shared with other users"  does that mean other users not related to your business?

Comment: My best guess is to eliminate things  router->dlink->single workstation, what happens? best guess is that it works better. If not then I'd go straight to the router->workstaton this will take some changes on the workstation but it will eliminate the dlink.